# JSON parse not working on html script element

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing

I am trying to convert to JSON the contents of a script in a HTML element. But the problem is that not all the keys have quotes. Here is the script:

```
{
  route: "PDFilter",
  websiteId: "52",
  lang: "us",
  layout: {
    PDPage: {
      Banner: 1,
      Spotlight: 1,
      HotProduct: 1,
      ContentSource: 0,
      SocialMedia: 0,
      ScenarioFilter: 1,
      CategoryHotProduct: 1,
      CategoryHotProduct_9: 0
    },
    PDPageSort: [
      "Banner",
      "Spotlight",
      "ScenarioFilter",
      "HotProduct",
      "CategoryHotProduct"
    ]
  },
  product: {
    l2id: "1",
    l3id: "20501",
    pdid: "0",
    layoutType: "2",
    theme: 1,
    IsCommercial: 0,
    bannerIsRoller: 0
  },
  productLine: {
    MDA: {
      Html: "",
      Image: ""
    },
    blackVersion: 0,
    rogVersion: 0
  },
  env: "prod",
  breadcrumb: {
    Home: {
      LevelName: "Home",
      Link: "//www.asus.com/us/"
    },
    L2: {
      LevelName: "Phones",
      Link: "//www.asus.com/us/Phone/"
    },
    L3: {
      LevelName: "ZenFone",
      Link: "//www.asus.com/us/Phone/ZenFone-Products/"
    }
  }
}
```

The parse says that is expecting a string, but that script is has the correct JSON format.

Comment: That looks like a JS object, not a JSON string. No need to parse an object, it is an object already.

Comment: If it was valid JSON it would have quotes around all the names

Comment: "**I am trying to convert to JSON the contents of a script in a HTML element.**". This makes me think OP is trying to convert that object to a JSON string. But they go onto say "**The parse says that is expecting a string, but that script is has the correct JSON format**". Maybe OP has gotten confused between [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: As @wing has correctly stated, it sounds like the OP wants to convert their Object to a JSON string. If this is the case, then this question is likely to be a dupe of another.

Comment: So I have that code that you see there in an HTML script element. When I get it using JS and strip the window.config = characters, it looks like the code you see. Since I get it using JS, it is a string, I do not need to stringify it. Once I have the correct object notation, I want to be able to access its properties for example code.route, but it is invalid since it is a string not an object. I need to convert that to an object, but it is not possible with the JSON parse method

Comment: Please explain all that in the question itself, and add the relevant code actually throwing the error.

Comment: Are you saying that the object above appears in a script element inside the HTML? And it is assigned to `window.characters`? You are *somehow* getting this object as a string (eg, using `el.textContent`)? And now you are trying to parse the string into an object? As @Teemu has said, please clarify your question with further information and add any more relevant code. Just going under the assumption the answers to my questions were "yes": is there not another way to get this object without having to resort to the string representation, such as accessing via the variable it is assigned to?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `JSON.parse` when you should be using `JSON.stringify`. `JSON.parse` is used to convert a JSON string to a JavaScript object while `JSON.stringify` is used to convert a JavaScript object to a JSON string.